# Get the current stacktrace of a java program while it's running

Tags: java, debugging, jar, execution

Suppose I ran a java program using the `java` command, is it possible to get the current position or stacktrace of the this program while it is running if I have the source code of that program? A solution which does not stop my program is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jps` to find the process id. `jstack` to dump the stack.

If it is running for the command line the `ctrl-Z`/`ctrl-break` (depending on platform) will also do the job.

Comment: Btw, look like ctrl-Z does not work for my platform (Red Hat linux 4.1.2-51), it seems like just putting my program into background, and I found under ctrl-Z, I can't even use jstack to spy it.

Comment: Er, `ctrl-3` I think was the alternative, but probably does the same? Usually `ctrl-z` would suspend (with `bg` to resume). Possibly something different is done with the signal handling.

Comment: Thank you. I think it's `fg` to resume, isn't it?

Comment: `fg` resumes on foreground, `bg` resumes on background. Another alternative is to issue a SIGQUIT (`kill -3 [pid]`), which will dump all the threads (and their stacktraces) to the STDOUT.

Answer (score 2):

Attach a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to the JVM and pause the JVM. The debugger can then show you the stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer a solution not stopping my program.